# Where do Material UI components get default colors?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I wanted to build a react application using Material UI. Also I was trying to set up the theme and everything in such a way that i wouldn't need (at least most of the time) to change the style of a single component. Trying to figure out how theme and palette work, i created a theme and put a simple Appbar in my application, just to see what it would look like.

I noticed that when the theme is 'light' mode the background color of the Appbar would be the one in palette.primary.main, but when theme is 'dark' mode it would not take the same value but instead the one in palette.background.paper which is confusing me a lot.

App components
`

```
function App() {
    // set up theme from theme.tsx
    const [theme, colorMode]: [Theme, { toggleColorMode: () => void }] = useMode();

    return (
        <ColorModeContext.Provider value={colorMode}>
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <CssBaseline/>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/" element={<Layout/>}>
                        <Route index element={<Home/>}/>
                        <Route path="*" element={<NoPage/>}/>
                    </Route>
                </Routes>
            </ThemeProvider>
        </ColorModeContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

Layout component

```
const Layout = () => {
    return(
        <Topbar></Topbar>
    )
}
```

Topbar component

```
export default function Topbar() {
    const theme = useTheme();
    return (
        <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
            <AppBar position="static">
                <Toolbar>
                    <IconButton
                        size="large"
                        edge="start"
                        color="inherit"
                        aria-label="menu"
                        sx={{ mr: 2 }}
                    >
                        <MenuIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                    <Typography variant="h6" component="div" sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
                        {theme.palette.primary.main}
                    </Typography>
                    <Button color="inherit">Login</Button>
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
        </Box>
    );
}
```

theme.tsx

```
export const themeSettings = (mode: PaletteMode) => {
    return {
        palette: {
            mode: mode,
            ...(mode === "light"
                ? {
                    primary: {
                        main: '#1a783e', //green
                    },
                    secondary: {
                        main: '#2e7306',
                    },
                    background: {
                        default: '#881212', //red
                        paper: '#0b2b7a', //blue
                    },
                }
                : {
                    primary: {
                        main: '#1a783e', //green
                    },
                    secondary: {
                        main: '#2e7306',
                    },
                    background: {
                        default: '#881212', //red
                        paper: '#0b2b7a', //blue
                    },
                }),
        },
    };
};

// context for color mode - a static object holding the function to change theme, this will be callable from every file
// just by importing it
export const ColorModeContext = createContext({
    toggleColorMode: () => {
    },
});

// custom hook, returns the theme and a setter function to change it
export const useMode = (): [Theme, { toggleColorMode: () => void }] => {
    const [mode, setMode] = useState<PaletteMode>("light");

    const colorMode = useMemo(
        () => ({
            toggleColorMode: () =>
                setMode((prev) => (prev === "light" ? "dark" : "light")),
        }),
        []
    );

    const theme = useMemo(() => createTheme(themeSettings(mode)), [mode]);
    return [theme, colorMode];
};
```

if mode=='light' the Top bar is green, but when I change it to 'dark' it turns blue which makes no sense to me, why?

Comment: I have found this site https://zenoo.github.io/mui-theme-creator to be very useful when editing MUI themes. You can use <ThemeProvider> and `createTheme` on your index.js for it to work